# StackImpact - What's your impact?

Tags: app, api-v2

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

I like to make contributions to Stack Exchange, and in return I gain rep. However, I find that rep doesn't really tell the whole story about what my contributions mean to the site. I thought it might be interesting to take the data offered by the API and come up with some "alternate stats" that might help me understand how my contributions effect the questions I participate in, and how that effects the site as a whole.

This app is the result of that experiment. With it, you can choose a Stack Exchange site and a week of the year, and it will look at what you did that week and what kind of effect you had. If you posted an answer, did people think it contributed to answering the question? How good was the question you asked versus the answers it generated? What kind of viewership did your question or answer generate?

In addition, I've provided some [QuantCast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantcast) data so you can put your contributions in perspective with the site as a whole.

Of course, like reputation, all of these "statistics" have their drawbacks, so I wouldn't take any of this too terribly seriously. It's a fun little experiment, and nothing more. :)

#### License

As all of my apps have been so far, all of the code I wrote is released under the terms of the BSD 2-clause license.

#### Usage

Click [this link](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/impact/) to load the app.

As in previous apps I've released, you'll need to click through an authorization dialog the first time in order to get an access token to fetch your account information.  Pick a site to query, and then choose a date using the datepicker. The data for that week will load shortly afterward. There's a bit of help text available that explains how the various columns are generated.

You can click column headers to sort. This is done via the [TableSort](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin for jQuery.

A couple of quick notes:

- If you've got multiple answers on the same question in the same week, right now I'm lumping them together.  If this bothers you, post an answer and if it gets a bunch of upvotes I'll change the behavior in 2.0 :)
- If you have more than 100 questions or 100 answers in a week, I'll only take the first 100.  This is another change that I could make in a 2.0 release, so request it if you're up against this limit.

### Code

This is 100% jQuery/Javascript, so everything is available in your browser.  All source is also available in this [GitHub Repo.](https://github.com/agent86ix/stackapps)

Answer (score 2):

Hmm… a couple of bugs in this:

- It doesn't seem to be accounted for that accepting your own answer doesn't earn any rep.
- Selecting a Sunday will make it load the *previous* week, instead of the one that includes the Sunday that has been selected.